# Sort function that sorts alphabetical and numbers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1103 [age] => 37 [gen] => C:3:2:5:1:4 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1104 [age] => 37 [gen] => A:3:1:4:1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1105 [age] => 36 [gen] => A:3:2:3:2  ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 1106 [age] => 32 [gen] => B:2:5:1:2:2 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 1107 [age] => 31 [gen] => C:3:4:4:5:3 [5] => Array ( [id] => 1104 [age] => 37 [gen] => A:3:1:4:1:6 ))
```

I want to sort the array by the gen key so the result will be like this:

A:3:1:4:1:6

A:3:2:3:2

B:2:5:1:2:2

C:3:2:5:1:4

C:3:4:4:5:3

I tried this code:

```
    uasort($newArray, function($a, $b) {
        return strnatcasecmp($a['ngen'], $b['ngen']);
    });
```

But can´t get the correct result. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use `$a['ngen']` in your sorting function when the array key is `gen` ?

Comment: Souldn't it be $a['gen'] and $b['gen']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will help you to sort the array, just pass the key by which the array is to be sort.

```
function build_sorter($key)
{
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}
```

Example Code:

```
$results = array(0 => array ( 'id' => 1103, 'age' => 37, 'gen' => 'C:3:2:5:1:4' ),
                  1 => array ( 'id' => 1104, 'age' => 37, 'gen' => 'A:3:1:4:1' ),
                  2 => array ( 'id' => 1105, 'age' => 36, 'gen' => 'A:3:2:3:2' ),
                  3 => array ( 'id' => 1106, 'age' => 32, 'gen' => 'B:2:5:1:2:2' ),
                  4 => array ( 'id' => 1107, 'age' => 31, 'gen' => 'C:3:4:4:5:3' ),
                  5 => array ( 'id' => 1104, 'age' => 37, 'gen' => 'A:3:1:4:1:6' )
                 ); 

usort($results, build_sorter('gen'));
echo "<pre>"; print_r($results) ;
```

Just call `build_sorter('gen')` in usort callback and pass key `gen`

This will hive you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1104
            [age] => 37
            [gen] => A:3:1:4:1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1104
            [age] => 37
            [gen] => A:3:1:4:1:6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1105
            [age] => 36
            [gen] => A:3:2:3:2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1106
            [age] => 32
            [gen] => B:2:5:1:2:2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1103
            [age] => 37
            [gen] => C:3:2:5:1:4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1107
            [age] => 31
            [gen] => C:3:4:4:5:3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Manjeet for your quick answer! 
Really simple and useful function that worked perfect.

Comment: @Michael welcome dear glad to help you :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ar = [
    ["id" => 1103, "age" => 37, "gen" => "C:3:2:5:1:4"], 
    ["id" => 1104, "age" => 37, "gen" => "A:3:1:4:1"], 
    ["id" => 1105, "age" => 36, "gen" => "A:3:2:3:2"], 
    ["id" => 1106, "age" => 32, "gen" => "B:2:5:1:2:2"], 
    ["id" => 1107, "age" => 31, "gen" => "C:3:4:4:5:3"], 
    ["id" => 1108, "age" => 37, "gen" => "A:3:1:4:1:6"], 
    ];

usort($ar, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['gen'], $b['gen']);
});

foreach($ar as $r)
    echo($r['id'] . " " . $r['gen'] . PHP_EOL);
```

Will give you:

```
1104 A:3:1:4:1
1108 A:3:1:4:1:6
1105 A:3:2:3:2
1106 B:2:5:1:2:2
1103 C:3:2:5:1:4
1107 C:3:4:4:5:3
```